# ActionLayout not showing when LayoutDirection is set to rtl

Tags: android, xml, xamarin.android

I have an actionLayout to work as a notification badge on my toolbar. When I have my Phone in ltr everything works fine. When I turn my phone to rtl locale the badge and the menu icon disappear, though they take space on toolbar and click on them is working. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

code

```
public override void OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
        {
            inflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.welcome_menu, menu);

            using (var icon = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.action_notification))
            {
                icon.Icon.ApplyDrawableTint(MobileSettingsManager.Instance.MobileSettings.Theme.NavigationBar.Icon);
                if ((Activity as BaseActivity).IsRtl() && Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
                {
                    icon.Icon.AutoMirrored = true;
                    var notification = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.action_notification).ActionView;
                    notification.Click += async delegate
                    {
                        if (Utils.IsOnline(Context))
                            await MoveToNotifications();
                    };
                    _badge = notification.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv_notif_count);
                    _badge.ApplyFont();
                    _badge.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                }
            }
            using (var icon = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.action_filter))
                icon.Icon.ApplyDrawableTint(MobileSettingsManager.Instance.MobileSettings.Theme.NavigationBar.Icon);
        }
```

welcome_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      >

  <item
    android:id="@+id/action_filter"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_filter"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

  <item
    android:id="@+id/action_notification"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/action_notification_badge"
    android:icon="@drawable/notification_bell"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

action_notification_badge.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton">
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hotlist_bell"
        android:src="@drawable/notification_bell"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="bell" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_notif_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="17sp"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@null"
        android:backgroundTint="#ff0000"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/hotlist_bell"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/hotlist_bell"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_square" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

rounded_square.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
  <solid
      android:color="#a3a3a3"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well after wasting a day on this bug, cause I had to use a `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` as a root for my `action_notification_badge.xml`. Generally, with `RelativeLayout` things get messed up (e.g. you can't make custom marker info windows in googlemaps with `RelativeLayout` as root element) so always prefer `LinearLayout`. My final code for `action_notification_badge.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton" >
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/hotlist_bell"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_notification"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
         android:contentDescription="bell" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_notif_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="17sp"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/hotlist_bell"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/hotlist_bell"
        android:textDirection="locale"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_square"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="@null" />
  </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```